# Hide "Create account" and change "Log in / create account with OpenID" in Media Wiki

Tags: openid, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I would like the OpenID login page for Media Wiki to be the main login page for my wiki, so I would like to hide the text "Create account" and change the "Log in / create account with OpenID" to "Log in / create account".

The [OpenID extension page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aOpenID) say you can do this with the variable "$wgOpenIDLoginOnly", but I cannot seem to make it work.

How can I edit configuration files to do this?

Comment: What version are you on? In earlier versions, that setting was called `$wgOpenIDOnly`

Comment: It is 1.21. That is what the wiki page says. I will try the one you mention.

Comment: 1.21 is the version of your MediaWiki. What is the version of your OpenID extension? Please paste the relevant versions from Special:Version (or provide a link to your wiki)!

Answer (score 0):

[Manual:Preventing access](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Removing_the_Login_link_from_all_pages) suggests to add in your `LocalSettings.php`:

```
function NoLoginLinkOnMainPage( &$personal_urls ){
    unset( $personal_urls['login'] );
    unset( $personal_urls['anonlogin'] );
    return true;
}
$wgHooks['PersonalUrls'][]='NoLoginLinkOnMainPage';
```